# What is the difference between {searchString} and {searchString*} FIND clauses in SOSL

Tags: sosl

I run 2 SOSL queries -

Query1:

```
FIND {Athreya}  
IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING Account(Id,Account_Number__c, RecordType.Name,Name LIMIT 16)
```

Result: 7 records whose field value contains 'Athreya'

Query2:

```
FIND {Athreya*}  
IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING Account(Id,Account_Number__c, RecordType.Name,Name LIMIT 16)
```

Result: 7 records whose field value contains 'Athreya'

According to my understanding, `Query1` should return records whose any field value = 'Athreya' and `Query2` should return records whose any field value contains 'Athreya' (for ex. Athreyas,Athreyag,..).
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The * after the word means "Starts With" not Contains.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. QUery2 should return records whose any field contain a word that starts with `Athreya` and has zero, one or more trailing characters. If you want to check for only one trailing character, use `?`. Query1 on the other hand only returns the records that contain the exact word `Athreya`

From - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

**Wildcards**

You can specify the following wildcard characters to match text patterns in your search:

* - Asterisks match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your search term. For example, a search for `john*` finds items that start with john, such as, `john`, `johnson`, or `johnny`. A search for `mi* meyers` finds items with `mike meyers` or `michael meyers`.

? - Question marks match only one character in the middle or end of your search term. For example, a search for `jo?n` finds items with the term `john` or `joan` but not `jon` or `johan`. You can't use a ? in a lookup search.